# Separating symbolic links in CPack for deb generation

Tags: cmake, debian, deb, cpack, software-packaging

I am trying to generate deb packages in CMake. The problem is, I am having trouble separating out the symbolic links so that it matches the standard conventions for Debian packages:

- lib<name>.deb

  - /usr/lib/<name>.so.<major version>.<minor version>
  - /usr/lib/<name>.so.<major version> -> sim link to first
- lib<name>-dev.deb

  - /usr/lib/<name>.so -> sim link to first
  - /usr/include/<name>.h

What I am wondering is, how can I separate the sym links out using CPack's DEB generator? Is there a way of putting the symbolic link in a different COMPONENT?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on IRC (#cmake@freenode) pointed out that I could use NAMELINK_ONLY for one install command and have a duplicate install with NAMELINK_SKIP. Then, if I specify different COMPONENTs for each, it has the behavior I'm looking for.

Example:

```
install(TARGETS project
        LIBRARY
        DESTINATION lib
        COMPONENT runtime
        NAMELINK_SKIP
)

install(TARGETS project
        LIBRARY
        DESTINATION lib
        COMPONENT dev
        NAMELINK_ONLY
)
```